# Best approach to execute method asynchronous from the gui

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im building an desktop application that is retrieving data from database every x seconds interval for displaying that data to a winform, i dont want to block my gui, i dont care if the method that retrieves the data takes a time while that time is less than the checking interval, i want that method asynchronous from the gui, what is the best approach and why? thanks im new to threading!

Background worker?
Thread.sleep?
ManualResetEvent?

Comment: Notice that `Task` class is available in .NET 4.0 and newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kamil has pointed out, `Tasks` is not available in older than .NET 4.0.

If you are stuck in the dark ages, the BackgroundWorker does a great job of this. In fact, this is probably what it was created for!

**Untested Pseudo Code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  private bool ok;
  private BackgroundWorker worker;

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    ok = true;
  }

  private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!worker.IsBusy) {
      worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
  }

  private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    var w = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    MyData inputData = (MyData)e.Argument;
    for (int i = 0; (i < NUM_TASKS) && !worker.CancellationPending; i++) {
      w.ReportProgress(i);
      // do tasks
    }
    e.Result = SomethingYouWantReturned();
  }

  private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (!ok) {
      worker.CancelAsync();
    }
  }

  private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Error != null) {
      ok = false;
      MessageBox.Show(this, e.Error.Message, "Error!");
    } else {
      var item = (TypeYouWantedReturned)e.Result;
      Console.WriteLine("Do something with `item`.");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: i have net framework 3.5, this example works for me!, but dont i need to use thread.sleep in the DoWork event? something like:

Thread.Sleep(1000);            
Method(parameters);

Comment: Skip the `Thread.Sleep(1000);` ...instead, set your timer to tick every 1000 ms. This is usually configured in the designer, so I didn't bother showing how to manually write the code for it.

Answer (score 2):

So you start out by saying that you want to perform a task every X seconds.  That tells us that we need a timer.  There are a lot to choose from though.  `System.Timer` should work fine for our purposes, but if you want to use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` you can.  You'll want to start the timer when you open the form, configure the interval to what you want, and assign a handler to run when the timer fires.

Next, when the timer fires you need to perform a database call and update the UI.  Performing a long running operation and then updating the UI with the results is what the `BackgroundWorker` class was tailor made for.  Set the `DoWork` method to do your database call, and have the `WorkerCompleted` event update the UI based on the results.  (The completed event will automatically be run in the UI thread; you don't need to manually marshal to that thread.)

You could also use Tasks to do these same things, if you have a new enough version of C#.  You could use `Task.Factory.StartNew` for the database call to have it run in a background thread, and then you can call `ContinueWith` on the `Task` it returns and use the overload that allows you to specify a synchronization context.  Here's a simple example:

```
private void handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => getInfoFromDB())
        .ContinueWith(task => label1.Text = task.Result,
        CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private string getInfoFromDB()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);//simulate long IO operation
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

Note that for this `Task` based example to work you would need to use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` timer, so that the tick event runs in the UI thread.

Comment: @dotNETbeginner In general you are correct, it is how I am using this specific Task that would require it to use a forms timer.  The call to `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` grabs the current context.  If the current context is a background thread then the continuation will run in a background thread.  We need the "current context" to be the UI thread, and the forms timer will ensure that the event handler runs in the UI thread.  There are other ways of accessing the sync context without using a forms timer, I just choose to do it this way.